# Flash 10.0 application doesn't get responses from HTTP server occasionally

Tags: flash, networking

I'm a developer of a social game built with Flash 10.0. I'm monitoring client errors log(which are sent to the server upon any fatal error on the client) alongside with server errors log.

There are some strange errors in the client log: some server responses simply don't reach the client. When the client sends a request to the server it also starts a 2 minutes timeout which is triggered when there is no response from the server. But according to the server log *there is* a response from the server.

In Flash I'm using URLLoader/URLRequest/URLVariables for network communication. For URLLoader I'm tracking events **HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS**, **SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR**, **IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR** but according to the client log there are no errors related to them...

Any idea why this can be happening?

**UPDATE:** Is there any chance some badly configured anti-virus/ad-blocker is rejecting server responses?

Comment: I have a similar problem when running against IIS7 on Windows7, some RemoteObject calls just don't get response!

Comment: Do you happen to have an anti-virus or ad-blocker?

Comment: I've got Avast! 6, no ad-blocker in my test browser.

Comment: Try disabling it temporarily...

Comment: Request is made on port 80? if so It shouldn't be blocked.

Comment: More then likely you are not setting the event up loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, infoIOErrorEvent);

Comment: Well, some antiviruses don't block the 80 port but they may block the contents if it contains(as they may think) malicious data

Comment: Regarinding IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, please read the original post. There is a listener for this type of event.

Comment: are you creating the loader in a function rather than as a class level object? Maybe its going out of scope. Also do you have multiple instances on the go at the same time? Flash has been known to fail silently if there are too many concurrent connections.

Comment: @Neil 'Flash has been known to fail silently if there are too many concurrent connections.' -- this could be it! do you have any references/links that discuss this?

Comment: I don't have any links for you, but I have had problems in the past when I have queued up multiple instances of the Loader instead of reusing the same one. Can you share some more code?

Comment: it's not that,.. I re-checked with my code and I did have RemoteObject calls in parallel command (robotlegs) but switched to sequence command, so single request at a time is dispatched. I don't know, I am going to implement more logging into server to better find a problem.

Comment: I suggest that you should do the following: 1 -- log all the ins and outs of the backend app (and, naturally, of the client app). 2 -- use Wireshark (it's free) to make sure you are sending what's intended from the client side. See if your request actually passes through client's network interface, and if it is well-formed. 3 -- log everything that is passing through server's network interface. I guess, you will have the whole picture. (I had a similar problem, and it was trojan stuff that were mangling HTTP messages damaging them in the process.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by caching client responses on the server and re-sending requests from the client after 30 seconds if there were no responses from the server. In order to achieve this I had to assign sequence id to every packet sent from the client so that I could track them on the server as well. So far it works just fine.